# Is it possible to map one string to another using a dictionary-like object in R?

Tags: r, dictionary

I want to map one string to another in R, using a dictionary-like object as seen in Python. For example, in Python, you can define a dictionary to convert one string to another, like:

```
d = {"s": "Superlative", "d": "Dynamic", "f": "Furious"}
pd.apply(lambda x: d[x["map_column"]], axis=1)
```

However, in R, if you want to convert a set of strings in one column to another one based on such mapping, you would end up defining a function that takes a lot of `if else`, like:

```
mapper <- function(x) {
    if (x = "s") {
        return ("Superlative")
    } else if (x = "d") {
            return ("Dynamic")
    }...

    return("")
}
```

But I don't like to define such a long, long function. So is it possible to define a dictionary, or more specifically, to get the result with far fewer, one-line (or two) code in R?

Comment: Use a join operation, e.g., merge, if you have a data.frame. Use a named vector if you have a vector. Not quite clear what you need.

Comment: what about labelling a factor?

Comment: an example: `txt <- sample(c("s", "d", "a"), 10, T)` ;  then
`factor(txt, levels=c("s", "d", "a"), labels=c("Superlative", "Dynamic", "another"))` or create a wee dictionary `mymap <- c("s"="Superlative", "d"="Dynamic", "a"="another")` ; `mymap[txt]`

Comment: or `switch(x, s = "Superlative", d = "Dynamic", f = "Furious", stop(x, ' not found'))`

Comment: @Roland I want to merge two dataframes, but because a column in one dataframe uses a shortcut character while the second one uses the full words, I first have to convert the shortcut character to full one before merging.

Comment: Create a lookup data.frame and do a merge to add a column with the full words.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're already using the [`tidyverse`](https://blog.rstudio.org/2016/09/15/tidyverse-1-0-0/), then this is what `recode` is for in `dplyr`.

```
df %>%
    mutate(LongName = recode(ShortName, 
                             s = "Superlative",
                             d = "Dynamic",
                             f = "Furious",
                             `multiple words` = "Use backticks to escape"
                             )
           ) ->
    df
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use an environment as a hash table:

```
dict <- new.env(hash = TRUE, parent = emptyenv(), size = NA)
## insert into hash table
dict[["s"]] <- "Superlative"
dict[["d"]] <- "Dynamic"
dict[["f"]] <- "Furious"
## query using key
key <- "s"
dict[[key]]
##[1] "Superlative"
key2 <- "f"
dict[[key2]]
##[1] "Furious"
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that this is easily achieved by defining a vector with an attached string, like:

```
map <- c("s"="Superlative", "d"="Dynamic", "f"="Furious")
df$longCharacter <- map(df$shortCharacter)
```

This is executed much like a dictionary in Python, in one-line code.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. I get Error: could not find function "map".

Comment: Should be more like this:

`df<- data.frame(shortCharacter = c("s","f","d","s"))`

`my_map <- c("s"="Superlative", "d"="Dynamic", "f"="Furious")`

`df$longCharacter <- my_map[df$shortCharacter]`

Comment: `map[df$shortCharacter]` (`[`, not `(`)